# How to test traffic/media quality for any H264 call

Tags: protocols, media, sip, h.264, traffic

How to test traffic/media quality for any H264 call
Including what parameters to test/look into for the media quality based tests.

Answer (score 0):

VoIP quality is mostly subjective. There are many contributing factors like packet loss, jitter, delay, etc that determine quality of your service. Anyway QoS measurment methods can be divided into two broad categories:

- Subjective methods like [MOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_opinion_score)
- Objective methods like R-Factor and E-Model

If you want to read more about these topics you can refer to a book like [Speech quality of VoIP assessment and prediction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470030607).

Also if you want a quick assessment there are some tools out there that can help you. For example [Homer](http://sipcapture.org) can calculate an objective quality of call using RTCP data.[VoIP Monitor](http://www.voipmonitor.org) is also a great tool.